# Thread safety issue during Async, how to get around this

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, dotnet-httpclient

I need to do 4 HttpClient requests from different method using the same HttpClient instance, which I think causing a thread safety issue. Let me explain this more.

Inside a Windows Phone application i'm developing there is a 'MainViewModel' class. This class has an async method to get data from a webserver and process the response. The Async method is named 'LoadData'. I even have 2 more Async methods ('ScheduleArrayAsync' and 'CurrActivityAsync') in this class to help process the data I'm getting from the server.

From the 'LoadData' method I do 3 HttpClient requests (this part is working like charm), while processing the response from all those three requests, I need to call 'ScheduleArrayAsync' method. From there I have to make a new HttpClient Request (here comes the problem). This last request will never generate and no error code is generated not even when I use try/catch statement.

What makes me think it's a threading issue is that, if I move the last HttpClient request to the 'LoadData' method, just as a test, it works again.

The MainViewModel class:-

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; private set; }

    private JsonTextWriter jsonW;

    private string Owner;

    private RequestResponse reqPList;

    public bool IsDataLoaded
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public async void LoadData()
    {
        var baseUri = new Uri("https://uri/");

        await CookieHandler.GetCookies(baseUri); // A separate request to get some cookies

        reqPList = new RequestResponse();  // The class that handle the Httpclinet

        await reqPList.GetResponse(baseUri, pList); // First request
        XmlConvertor.ConvertToXml(reqPList.Response);
        var phoneListResponse = XmlConvertor.XmlString;

        await reqPList.GetResponse(baseUri, currActiv); // Second request
        XmlConvertor.ConvertToXml(reqPList.Response);
        var currActivResponse = XmlConvertor.XmlString;

        await reqPList.GetResponse(baseUri, sched);  // Third request
        XmlConvertor.ConvertToXml(reqPList.Response);
        var schedResponse = XmlConvertor.XmlString;

        //await reqPList.GetSlotInforPOST("154215");
        var handler = new DataHandler();
        await handler.phoneListHandler(phoneListResponse);
        await handler.CurrActivitiesHandler(currActivResponse);
        await handler.ScheduleHandler(schedResponse);
        /// Do some processing included call this line 

                    #region Current activity
                    CurrActivityAsync(item, handler.currActivitiesJSON);
                    #endregion


        this.IsDataLoaded = true;
    }

    private async void CurrActivityAsync(JToken token, string jString)
    {
        // Some processing
    }

    private async void ScheduleArrayAsync(JToken token, string jString)
    {
        try
        {
            // Do some more processing and call the fourth request 
                            if (addedInfo[0].Contains("slotInfo"))
                                await reqPList.GetSlotInforPOST(addedInfo[1]);
                            else if (addedInfo[0].Contains("vacationInfo"))
                                await reqPList.GetVacationSlotInfoPOST(addedInfo[1], addedInfo[2]);

        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {

            var d = exp.Message;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the RequestResponse class:-

```
public class RequestResponse
{
    public string Response { get; private set; }

    private HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        UseCookies = true,
        CookieContainer = CookieHandler.Cookiejar,
        AllowAutoRedirect = false,
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip
    });

    public async Task<string> GetResponse(Uri baseuri, string uriString)
    {
        if (client.BaseAddress == null)
        {
            client.BaseAddress = baseuri; 
        }
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xhtml+xml"));
        var response = await client.GetAsync(baseuri + uriString);
        string webresponse = null;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var resp = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            var encode = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
            var respString = encode.GetString(resp, 0, resp.Length - 1);
            webresponse = respString;
        }
        return Response = webresponse;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetSlotInforPOST(string timeId)
    {
        /// If the method is called from inside 'LoadData' it works.
        /// But if it is called from inside ScheduleArrayAsync, it will break at line marked with //***
        try
        {
            var baseUri = new Uri("https://uri/");
            const string slotInfo = "cgi-bin/slotInfo.pl";

            if (client.BaseAddress == null)
                client.BaseAddress = baseUri;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
            HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("timeId",timeId)
            });
            var response = await client.GetAsync(baseUri + slotInfo);  // ***
            string webresponse;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var respo = await client.PostAsync(baseUri + slotInfo, content);
                var resp = await respo.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                var encode = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
                var respString = encode.GetString(resp, 0, resp.Length - 1);
                webresponse = respString;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            var s = exp.Message;
        }
        return Response;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetVacationSlotInfoPOST(string vacationId, string date)
    {
        // Do some HttpClient Request
    }
}
```

Am I understanding the issue right? How to overcome it? as I really need to make the last HttpClient Request from 'ScheduleArrayAsync' and not from 'LoadData'

**Edit**
Just wanted to mention that during my efforts to solve the problem I had different instance of HttpClient in each method inside the RequestResponse class. Beside as I mentioned above, when I call the fourth request from inside 'LoadData' method everything is working as it is intended even when it's one instance of httpclient.

Comment: `using the same HttpClient instance`. And you do this why? Are you somehow attached to it? You can create a new one and not have any of those problems.

Comment: @nvoigt - almost to the letter what I was going to post:)

Comment: @nvoigt isn't it better performance wise? I think I read something about this here:- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4e12d8e2-e0bf-4654-ac85-3d49b07b50af/best-practice-usage-of-httpclient-for-rest-calls-maximum-throughput?forum=netfxnetcom

Comment: Anyhow will try this when I'm back home, if nothing new comes up.

Comment: @DreamNet indeed, it is. But "correct result" beats "performance" in almost all cases :)

Comment: @nvoigt because HttpClient has been designed to be reused and there are a significant number of advantages to doing so. There is no problem re-using HttpClient.  However, there is a bunch of weird stuff going on in these class that could cause threading issues.

Comment: @DarrelMiller can you please explain more about what you mean in your last statement? It might helps me.

Comment: @nvoigt please look at the updated info

Comment: Off the top of my head, move the code that sets the BaseAddress into the constructor.  Also, the same for DefaultHeaders.  If you need to change the accept on a per-request basis, then create a HttpRequestMessage instance, change that and use SendAsync.  ConvertToXml is setting a static, change it to return the XML instead.  You are not checking the status code from your PostAsync method.

Comment: @DarrelMiller Thanks for the tips i will try them now. Do you Think this might be the cause?

Comment: @DarrelMiller I really don't get why when moving await reqPList.GetSlotInforPOST(addedInfo[1]); from 'ScheduleArrayAsync' method to 'LoadData' method, Everything is working but not if i keep it

Comment: @DreamNet  It's possibly you have async void as the signature.  That will swallow any exceptions that are raised.  Change it to async Task.

Comment: @DarrelMiller please check the answer i post it, esp. the last line ;) Thanks bro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possibly the async void that you have as the signature in some methods. Using async void will prevent calling functions from trapping throw exceptions. Exceptions thrown from async void methods can only be trapped by global exception handlers.

Comment: While I agree that the use of `async void` was the source of the problem, it's not because it swallows exceptions. Quite the contrary; `async void` will surface the exceptions very loudly.

Comment: @StephenCleary Does my revision sound better?

Answer (score 0):

Lastly i have fixed it, thanks to Darrel.

To fix the problem i needed to change the signature of 'CurrActivityAsync' method.

from

```
private async void CurrActivityAsync(JToken token, string jString)
```

to

```
private void CurrActivityAsync(JToken token, string jString)
```

As this method had no await inside it that is why it didn't need async in the signature. My bad i didn't mentioned that in my original post.

This was the only thing i needed to do, But i even changed the signature of my 'ScheduleArrayAsync'
to be more correct for Async.

from

```
private async void ScheduleArrayAsync(JToken token, string jString)
```

to

```
private async Task ScheduleArrayAsync(JToken token, string jString)
```

**Darrel** please can you write your last comment as an answer so you get some credits.